# Kubernetes - error: no resource "deployment" has been defined

Tags: kubernetes

I've install Kubernetes 1.3.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 server as a single-node-cluster.
I'm able to deploy docker images successfully and access the running container via HTTP and see them in `docker ps`.

When I try to follow the [Kubernetes-Quick-Start](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/quick-start/) after running the command `kubectl run my-nginx --image=nginx --replicas=2 --port=80` the output is

```
CONTROLLER   CONTAINER(S)   IMAGE(S)   SELECTOR       REPLICAS
my-nginx     my-nginx       nginx      run=my-nginx   2
```

and it is not `deployment "my-nginx" created`.

Also when I run `kubectl expose deployment my-nginx --target-port=80 --type=LoadBalancer` I get the error:

> error: no resource "deployment" has been defined

Did I miss something during the setup?

Comment: What is the output of `kubectl version`?

Answer (score 0):

I was using an old version of Kubernetes 1.0.1.\
After update to 1.3.5 this was fixed.